# How can I mock a Promise return value in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine

I'm writing unit tests for a method that has a promise chain.

I want to make sure that when the promise resolves, my process function gets called. And when a promise is rejected, my handleError function gets called.

How can I mock a return value to reach the .then block? I don't want to call through to the service method.

```
//### inside my controller class
submitForm() {
    this.myService.sendApiRequest(form, params)
        .then((resp:IResp) => {
           console.warn('inside .then');
           this.processResponse(resp, form);
        })
        .catch((e:IServerError) => {
           console.warn('inside .catch');
           this.handleError(e);
        });
}
```

Here is my spec

```
//### spec

    describe('when the API call succeeds', function () {
        beforeEach(function createSpies() {
            spyOn(this.myService, 'sendApiRequest').and.returnValue($q.resolve({}));
            spyOn(myMethod, 'processResponse');
        });

        it('should call the "processResponse" method', function () {
            component.submitForm(this.form);

            expect(
                this.processResponse
            )
            .toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
```

Test fails with:

> Expected spy processResponse to have been called.

I'm using Typescript 2, Angular 1.5 and Jasmine 2.

---

**EDIT: As often happens, after writing this question up I'm wondering if this test is even useful. Am I just testing that Angular's Promise implementation works? Or is this the right way to get "100% coverage" for the method?**

Comment: You're testing how submitForm works, so it's ok. You need to trigger a digest to execute promise chains in test, $rootScope.$digest().

Comment: This kind of tests have little value IMO. it tests "How the code runs" and not "what the code does". 

Its usfull when you try to reach 100% coverage.

testing this.processResponse & this.errorHandler has more value, and you don't need to mock anything for that.

Comment: @GuyYogev Yes, "how" vs "what" is exactly what I was afraid of. I agree with your sentiment.

Comment: @estus and voila, it worked. thanks! do you want to post an answer so i can accept?

Comment: @user2954463 I guess dupe question already answers that. And no, I find this perfectly valid way to test things. There's more than one opinion on the subject, but 'how' vs 'what' is basically unit vs functional tests. Usually it's beneficial to test 'what' in e2e tests, while fine-grained unit tests test 'how', line by line. In this case there's no need for intermediate tests. Because when you've tested submitForm and then tested processResponse and handleError, you've got full coverage.